# Parallel flashcards in Anki

Tags: anki

Is there any possible way to create two flashcards at the same time in Anki?
Basically, can you **add** several flashcards at the same time? (having many '***add***' tabs/windows open at the same time).

*(I use the **desktop** version, in LinuxMint)*

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would like to do? The question is very wide and ambiguous, so please give an example of what you want to see happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the ["Multiple Add and Browser Windows" add-on](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/969743069).

Answer (score 0):

I was solving a similar problem. There is a tool for mass creation of anki cards in the deck container, using python scripts - genanki. I like this option the most.

You can also use a script to generate a large number of cards in txt, csv, xls, xml, etc. format and then import them into anki using addons.